# Code translate from C/C++ to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, translate

i have a little problem. I want to translate a little code from C/C++ to Delphi.

```
LPVOID lpMyVar;

*(LPWORD)lpMyVar = 0xF9EB;
```

I have tried several ways, but to no avail. If anyone can help me please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the actual declaration of these variables in C/C++? You don't show that. And what's the significance of `LPVOID = lpMyVar;`? It looks a little peculiar out of context.

Comment: sorry, it is LPVOID lpMyVar;

Comment: What are you going to run that on (or whate happens next with lpMyVar)? Seems like something that probably isn't very portable anyways.

Comment: resolved! Thank you too!

Comment: In the interest of having a more descriptive title question (one that couldn't be applied to *hundreds* of other questions), could you please describe which part of the code gave you trouble? Was it the two-token statement without any punctuation between them? Was it the asterisk? Was it the single token in parentheses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type PDWORD = ^DWORD;
var lpMyVar: Pointer;

PDWORD(lpMyVar)^ := $F9EB;
```

But it might be better to declare `lpMyVar` as a typed pointer:

```
var lpMyVar: ^DWORD;

lpMyVar^ := $F9EB;
```

Comment: For newer versions, and x64 support, use `NativeUInt` instead of DWORD.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez DWORD isn't used as a typecast of the pointer here, so PDWORD (leading "P") is used to cast the untyped pointer into a typed pointer. No NativeUInt is required here unless the accessed data is a 64bit integer in x64.